# Efficiently find a border around a binary group of points

Tags: math

This is more of a mathematical question.

I have a list of 2D coordinates of length N. (Nx2 list)

The coordinates are rounded numbers and form a region. The following is an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7hrh.png)

What I would like is to have a border around these points. Like the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUq3T.png)

One option to do this is to

1. go through the list, and for each coordinate i
2. check for the 8 possible neighbours j to see
3. if this point doesn't overlap with given coordinates k .
4. if this point doesn't overlap with already found border coordinates

This works well, nut needs N*N*8 calculations. For my N=1000 points: 8 million!

Does anyone know how this could be done more efficient?

Best regards,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the grid is constrained and is on the order of N as well, you could do better and get to O(N) by making a 2-D array of ints the size of the grid.

Initialize the grid to zeros.

For each point in the list of points, set the point itself to negative in the grid array and set each neighbor that isn't negative to positive.

When you're done, each point in the 2-D grid array that's positive is the border.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Transforming the list of coordinates to a 2D grid is certainly possible. I am definitely going to test your idea and compare the amount of operations! I am however afraid that is leads to very large 2D matrices, with a lot of white space. Worst case scenario is a diagonal type of region which would give 1000x1000 matrix at maximum.

Comment: Yeah. A diagonal would certainly violate the "on the order of N" size constraint for the grid. If the grid is on the order of N * N, then this method will be O(N*N) just like your original post's method.

Answer (score 0):

Make a sorted container that enforces uniqueness (in c++ STL, that's a std::set) of coordinates. Go through the points, adding each point's eight neighbors to the set if they aren't already in there. Then go though the points a second time, subtracting them from the set if they are in the set. The points that remain are the border. That's O(N*log(N)). In general that's the best you can do. But see my other answer for a better algorithm if additional criteria exist.